# What is url of Mastercard hpf.js script?

Tags: html, mastercard, hpf

I'm trying to implement the HPF interface to Mastercard.  Their web site includes a url to the Javascript file required for that. It's

```
<script id="hpfScript" src="https://in.gateway.mastercard.com/form/v3/hpf.js"></script>
```

But my html says it can't find it.  Can somebody suggest a working url?

Used that url, but it can't be found.

Comment: Why do you think asking here would be better than contacting MasterCard?

Comment: It might help if you clarify which particular implementation you're working against. This one? https://network.gateway.mastercard.com/api/documentation/integrationGuidelines/hostedCheckout/integrationModelHostedCheckout.html?locale=en_US

Comment: Sorry, the url I'm using is <script id="hpfScript" src="https://in.gateway.mastercard.com/form/v3/hpf.js"></script>

Comment: The documentation I'm using is https://na-gateway.mastercard.com/api/documentation/integrationGuidelines/hostedPaymentForm/HPFJS/buildYourIntegration.html?locale=en_US

Comment: Note: I *did* contact Mastercard.  Seems like $55/month is a bit much for answering a simple url question.

Comment: That documentation says to use `https://na-gateway.mastercard.com/form/v3/hpf.js`. Where did you get `https://in.gateway.mastercard.com/form/v3/hpf.js` from? (Both URLs work in browser. What *specific* error do you get in your implementation?)